# Installation of Ubuntu 12.04 in VMware

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32bit) on VMware 7... But it gives this message "The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. You will need to power off or reset the virtual machine at this point."... My OS is win7 (64bit). What would be the problem. Plz help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue with Kernel of OS and VMWare version you are using. Check the thread [here](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/284658?start=0&tstart=0) and see if it helps

Comment: Ok I will check and let you know as I am not in front of that PC where I was working. But for your kind information, I think it is enabled as I am running different OS such as Win XP, Mikrotik OS in that same VMware.

Comment: I am sorry, I read your question wrong - I am updating answer with appropriate details.

Comment: Thanks... ya your guessing is right. After upadating VMware version to 9 now its perfectly working.